# Short story - alien harvests human nerves

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, horror

I read it in a book of short stories, possible a scifi book? A decade ago.

It's about a person who wakes up during the process of an alien harvesting their nerves, he can't move.

Literally all I remember, it was a one scene short story in a short story.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.